# How do I call a function that requires a 'static lifetime with a variable created in main?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've got a struct defined that has a function which defines a static lifetime:

```
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn doSomething(&'static self) {
        // Some code goes here
    }
}
```

I'm consuming it from main like so:

```
fn main() {
    let obj = MyStruct {};
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

It's intended for the `doSomething` call to block and execute for the lifetime of the application.

I'm running into issues with the lifetime checks where it's stating that it may outlive the `main` function, which seems strange to me as once `main` is complete the application should exit.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Boiethios exactly what I stated, that function calls another function which requires a static lifetime, so the function itself requires a static lifetime in order to conform to those requirements. I need to call that function from main, which the compiler prevents due to the struct apparently outliving main.

Comment: What is this function that requires a static lifetime?

Comment: Your problem is that you require the reference to self to have a static livetime but it is defined in the main function. Try: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0641e22a79898b268dec91e05ac1d160&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: @Boiethios hyper requires a static runtime when running the server and processing each request. What's worse is it's actually two layers of static requirements (two closures).

Comment: @raggy unfortunately I have tried that, but it doesn't support dynamically configuring the struct, you have to have a plain struct value.

Comment: @lyptt Maybe you can use a lazy static

Comment: @Boiethios That solved it! Can you submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @lyptt Sorry, I was busy. You can accept one of the answers that suit you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The naive way to do this is with a `static` variable, but it will require unsafe code if you need to actually set the value inside your `main` function:

```
static mut OBJ: MyStruct = MyStruct;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        OBJ = MyStruct {};
        OBJ.doSomething();
    }
}
```

It's also `unsafe` to do pretty much anything with a mutable static thereafter.

The much better way to do it is to let a library ([`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static)) take care of the unsafe code.

```
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

fn main() {
    lazy_static!{
        static ref OBJ: MyStruct = MyStruct {};
    }
    OBJ.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 21):

The *primary* way to create a reference that has the `'static` lifetime is to make the variable `static`. A static variable is one that can be created at *compile time*:

```
struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn do_something(&'static self) {}
}

static OBJ: MyStruct = MyStruct;

fn main() {
    OBJ.do_something();
}
```

As Rust's constant evaluation story improves, this will be more common, but it will never allow configuration at runtime.

A far less common method is to deliberately leak memory, producing a reference that will last "forever". This should be discouraged because leaking memory isn't a good thing:

```
fn main() {
    let obj = Box::leak(Box::new(MyStruct));
    obj.do_something();
}
```

There's also the possibility of creating a singleton:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)
- [How can you make a safe static singleton in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221504/155423)

> as once `main` is complete the application should exit.

Perhaps, but the compiler doesn't treat `main` specially for lifetime purposes.

---

> hyper requires a static runtime when running the server and processing each request.

No, it doesn't. It has a bound of `: 'static`, which means that any references passed in must be `'static`, but you don't have to pass in a bare reference at all.

For patterns like this, the most common thing is to pass in something like an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). This allows sharing of the underlying resource.

```
pub fn do_something<F, T>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> T + 'static,
    T: 'static,
{
    // "spawn" 3 threads
    f();
    f();
    f();
}

struct MyStruct;

static OBJ: MyStruct = MyStruct;

fn main() {
    // OK
    do_something(|| &OBJ);

    // Not OK
    let another = MyStruct;
    do_something(|| &another);

    // OK
    use std::sync::Arc;
    let shared = Arc::new(MyStruct);
    do_something(move || shared.clone());
}
```

You can even use [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/#when-to-choose-interior-mutability) if you wanted dynamic reconfiguration.

See also:

- [How do I use static lifetimes with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30562443/155423)

Comment: Yeah I've got a wrapper class that needs a reference to `self`, I can pass in an Arc which works around that particular issue but it still has various `'static` complaints.

Comment: @Shepmaster from the rust reference "Static items do not call drop at the end of the program" so static and Box::leak are basically identical, except the latter are on the heap. Honestly given how annoying rust is about initializing static variables, Box::leak seems like a superior way to create static variables with runtime initialization.

Comment: @Eloff I don't understand what the goal of your comment is. The answer already lists leaking memory as a solution.

Comment: @Shepmaster You mentioned "This should be discouraged because leaking memory isn't a good thing", and indeed it sounds scary. But that's exactly how rust static works anyway, so I don't think it should be discouraged for this specific use case.